# Scourgify is easy, so why is the Hog's Head so dirty?

Tags: harry-potter

As is mentioned repeatedly in chapter 16 of *Order of the Phoenix* the Hog's Head pub is filthy. How can this be? From what I remember of the earlier books, Scourgify is so easy to cast that it's taught to pre-teens. In fact, given that Hermione knows how to cast it, why would Professor Flitwick recommend that she brings her own glass?

Comment: It's called a plothole.

Comment: Wiping (your side of) the table with a napkin is also SO DAMN EASY that every muggle pre-schooler knows how to do it, yet very few people (young or adult) care enough to do so.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's (apparently) not all that easy to cast, has a limited effective area, and doesn't seem to work especially well against heavy staining and grime.

> ‘Ah, well,’ said Tonks, slamming the trunk’s lid shut, ‘at least it’s all in. That could do with a bit of cleaning, too.’ She pointed her wand at Hedwig’s cage. ‘Scourgify.’ A few feathers and droppings vanished. **‘Well, that’s a bit better – I’ve never quite got the hang of these householdy sort of spells.** Right – got everything? Cauldron? Broom? Wow! – A Firebolt?’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sup></sub>

The fact that they're advised to bring their own glasses to the pub would suggest that the owner isn't big on cleaning spells either, given that he's seen to be wiping out glasses with a rag. On top of that you can hardly use *scourgify* once you've already received your drinks in a dirty glass.

It also occurs that the lack of cleanliness may be the bar's *theme*. Note the dirty windows and poor lighting. All of these seem to be designed to attract a certain clientele (denizens, really) more comfortable being in an environment where privacy is closely guarded.

Comment: Back in the late 90's I went to a bar in Sao Paulo, for which parts of it hadn't been cleaned since Brazil last won the world cup, (or something like that).  It was actually the theme of the bar, and there was a huge layer of dust/dirt on those parts.

Comment: Diagon Alley is also dark and dirty, despite the ready availability of slave labour to clean it.

Comment: In principle the same reasons muggle bars can be dirty, I mean, a dishwasher is easy to use and wiping away dust can be as fast as casting a spell and yet...

Comment: @Valorum - do you mean Diagon Alley or Knockturn Lane?

Comment: @davidbak - I *did* meant Knocturn Alley, but actually the point stands. You wouldn't want to eat off the floor in either place, despite that they could easily have squads of slave cleaners making every flat surface spotless with magic.

Comment: It's called "ambience".  Would you want to eat in a restaurant that looks as sterile as a hospital operating room?  I mean, okay, right now that kind of sounds appealing, but let's say we're not in the middle of a worldwide pandemic.  An overly clean world would just feel oppressive...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - In a world where cleaning a room simply meant waving your wand for a few seconds, I'd expect *everything* to be sterile and spotless.

Comment: @Valorum I think you meant the streets of Hogsmeade. I dearly hope you realize that the Hog's Head is in Hogsmeade, not Diagon or Knockturn Alley.